# Proof that a sequence is bounded.

Tags: analysis

I am attempting to prove that the infinite sequence;

$1,-2,3,-4,....$

is unbounded to get a better understanding of sequences.

Suppose that the sequence $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},...$ defined by $a_{n}=(-1)^{n-1} . n$ for $ n \in N $, is bounded by $M$, such that $|a_{n}| \leq M$ for any $n$. where $M$ is a rational number such that $M \ge 0$.

since $M$ is a rational number, there exists an integer p such that $ p \le M < p+1 $, taking absolute values $ |p| \le |M| < |p+1| \le |p|+|1|$.

I need to show that $|p+1|=|a_n|$ for some n... i think. This will be my contradiction.

Comment: For all $n ∈ ℕ$, $|a_n| = n$? To prove things, it is *very* helpful to define them in a rigorous manner. Define $a_n = …$

Comment: Note that $|a_n|=n$, hence $|a_n|\le M$ fails as soon as $n>M$ (which happens by the Archimedean property)

Comment: You have $a_{2n+1} = 2n+1$. Choose some $M$ and pick $n \ge M$, then $a_{2n+1}>M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|a_{p+1}| = |(-1)^{p} \cdot (p+1)| = |p+1|$$

So, $|M| < |a_{p+1}|$ and the sequence is thus unbounded because your premise that $|a_n| < |M|$ for any $n$ is shown to be false.

Comment: would the power of -1 be p? i know regardless the absolute value would be the same. and thank you ever so much!

Comment: @HMPARTICLE Yes, my bad.